# Trying to animate the view in pygame but It only does when I move my mouse

Tags: python, pygame

I've just started learning PyGame and now I'm trying to animate my view but unexpectedly, it only does happen when I move my mouse. I have no idea why it happens to be like this. Do you know what causes that?

Here's the code:

```py
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()

screenWidth = 1280
screenHeight = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
wood_bg = pygame.image.load('my_pic.jpg') # Background
land_bg = pygame.image.load('archive/Land_BG.png') # Animated
land_pos = 650
land_dir = "UP"
water_bg = pygame.image.load('archive/Water_BG.png') # Animated
water_pos = 630
water_dir = "UP"


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        screen.blit(wood_bg,(0,0))
        screen.blit(land_bg,(0,land_pos))
        screen.blit(water_bg,(0,water_pos))

        # Animate water and land
        if land_pos <= 520:
            land_dir = "DOWN"
        elif land_pos >= 620:
            land_dir = "UP"  
        
        if land_dir == 'UP':
            land_pos -= 2
        else:
            land_pos += 2
        
        if water_pos <= 630:
            water_dir = "DOWN"
        elif water_pos >= 680:
            water_dir = "UP"  
        
        if water_dir == 'UP':
            water_pos -= 1
        else:
            water_pos += 1

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: You need to unindent all of your code in the `for event in pygame.event.get()` for loop except for the quit condition. It's only running when that for loop runs, meaning it only does your animation when pygame sends in MOUSEMOTION events.

Comment: Sorry mate, was going to click on another button. Realized it now. There you go, corrected it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to draw the scene and update the display in the application loop instead of the event loop:

```py
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|

    screen.blit(wood_bg,(0,0))
    screen.blit(land_bg,(0,land_pos))
    screen.blit(water_bg,(0,water_pos))

    # Animate water and land
    if land_pos <= 520:
        land_dir = "DOWN"
    elif land_pos >= 620:
        land_dir = "UP"  
    
    if land_dir == 'UP':
        land_pos -= 2
    else:
        land_pos += 2
    
    if water_pos <= 630:
        water_dir = "DOWN"
    elif water_pos >= 680:
        water_dir = "UP"  
    
    if water_dir == 'UP':
        water_pos -= 1
    else:
        water_pos += 1

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Answer (score 2):

It was a minor indentation error. You had the rest of your code (after the `for loop`: `for event in pygame.event.get():` nested under this `for loop`. This meant that the code below was only running when it received an `event`. Why it only moved when your mouse moved, was because this `event` every time, was your **mouse moving event**. If your mouse is still, then there is no event called.

### Here is the revised code for reference:

```py
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()

screenWidth = 1280
screenHeight = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    
wood_bg = pygame.image.load('my_pic.jpg') # Background
land_bg = pygame.image.load('archive/Land_BG.png') # Animated
land_pos = 650
land_dir = "UP"
water_bg = pygame.image.load('archive/Water_BG.png') # Animated
water_pos = 630
water_dir = "UP"


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # >>> All this code below had an extra indent, thus running under the "for loop" above
    screen.blit(wood_bg,(0,0))
    screen.blit(land_bg,(0,land_pos))
    screen.blit(water_bg,(0,water_pos))

    # Animate water and land
    if land_pos <= 520:
        land_dir = "DOWN"
    elif land_pos >= 620:
        land_dir = "UP"  
    
    if land_dir == 'UP':
        land_pos -= 2
    else:
        land_pos += 2
    
    if water_pos <= 630:
        water_dir = "DOWN"
    elif water_pos >= 680:
        water_dir = "UP"  
    
    if water_dir == 'UP':
        water_pos -= 1
    else:
        water_pos += 1

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(120)
```

Comment: @EfeFRK My pleasure. May I ask, how could my answer have been improved?